# ValueError: arrays must all be same length (Handling with try except)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, valueerror, except

I have the `for-loop` in the `try` and `except` to handle the

```
Value-error: arrays must all be same length
```

But it doesn't work as I am still getting the same error.

```
try:
        query = row[0]
        for result_url in search(query, safe='off', num=1, start=0, stop=1, domains=None, pause=3.0,
                                 only_standard=False, user_agent=None):
            results[query].append(result_url)
    except (IndentationError, IndexError, UserWarning, MemoryError, ValueError, OSError, UnicodeDecodeError) as e:
        continue
```

Comment: Are you trying to ignore the error?

Comment: The try and except is going to show you the error, so if you want to ignore the error and continue, use `pass` instead of `continue`.

Comment: @HjSin I Think He Want To ignore The Error and Continue

Comment: @HamzaLachi Ya, I'm guessing that too. So, using `pass` should do it.

Comment: after the try-except, i will write the results into a csv file. what happens is that the program throws out the value-error instead of putting out the csv file